# Is There A Guide to Debian Live's Seemingly Undocumented Ubuntu Extension?

Tags: customization, documentation

[Debian Live](http://live.debian.net/) is the tool used to generate LiveCD images now for Ubuntu.  There is a [manual available for it](http://live.debian.net/manual/3.x/index.en.html) that notes there is an extension that handles producing Ubuntu-style LiveCDs but says very little about what said extensions do.  Ubuntu is [listed on the downstream projects page](http://live.debian.net/project/downstream/) yet there is nothing for our usage of Debian Live.

There is a blueprint from the O cycle [logged on the wiki logged by Colin Watson](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/SwitchToLiveBuild).  That's the only thing I could find that tangentially talks about this on the wiki.  Elsewhere searches just lead back to the web-based copies of manual pages.

The main reason for doing this is to avoid going down the route discussed [here of building a bespoke netboot image with a tightly tuned preseed](http://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu) for my BeagleBoard-xM.  A way to do this using live-build would be nice.  It would also be nice to be able to keep disc images re-spun with updates for those Erie Looking Productions may pick up as collaborators who want to migrate to *buntu.

Comment: I have used live-build in Ubuntu quite a bit. There isn't really an "extension" as such. You can run live-build to create Ubuntu ISO images or img files pretty easily. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Mostly I've made ISOs just fine with it.  I figured out how to modify the ubuntu-defaults-image wrapper to build Xubuntu and Lubuntu images too.  Building an armhf image has been the tricky part thus far that I haven't figured out so I can make a nice image for my BeagleBoard-xM without doing a netboot installation on it instead.  The live-build documentation notes, too, that flipping the ubuntu mode flag on changes some behaviors in live-build but sadly never says **what actually changes**.

Comment: I just asked Colin Watson about this, knowing he knows live-build well. Unfortunately the cross-building stuff is in live-build 3 but it doesn't seem to be well documented anywhere. You'd have to dig through the live-build source to figure it out.

Comment: Could you please go ahead and make that an answer I can accept to close out the question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Alan Pope, there is not currently documentation for cross-building for ARM with live-build and it will be necessary to pore over the source code.  The documentation does not exist...***yet***.